# Math behind predicting the dimensions of bounding boxes

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, yolo

I have been trying to understand the mechanics behind YOLO v3. I got stuck at the section which defines the **calculation of bounding box.**

Going through various blogs, I found that

> The dimensions of the bounding box are predicted by applying a log-space transform to the output and then multiplying with an anchor.

However, none of the blogs explain how do we reach at the above calculation.

My questions are:

1. How do we reach at the above calculation ?
2. How relevant it is to delve into such details ? I am just staring to learn Computer Vision and wonder if I should worry about Maths like the above, or should I just take them as fundamental truths.

Comment: Sounds more like a software question, so you'd be better at stackoverflow

Comment: @Ben: No, this is a ML Theory/Math question. I posted this on SO earlier, the question was down-voted and closed. Here is the link to that question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71396449/math-behind-predicting-the-dimensions-of-bounding-boxes